# How to configure a vscode workspace with multiple DevContainers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am developing a Web Application with a Node/JS frontend and a Python backend. Development is done in two DevContainer environments with one DevContainer definition for each sub-project. So far, I open two instances of `vscode`, one for each sub-project. Each of the DevContainer setups mounts the overall project folder and points the workfolder to the right sub-folder. Also, I use a common `docker-compose.yml` to place both containers into the same docker network and to add a database.

```
my_project/
  docker-compose.yml
  backend/
    .devcontainers/
      devcontainer.json
      docker-compose.yml
      Dockerfile
  frontend/
    .devcontainers/
      devcontainer.json
      docker-compose.yml
      Dockerfile
```

A `devcontainer.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Python & Poetry",
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../../docker-compose.yml",
        "./docker-compose.yml"
    ],
    "service": "demo",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
...
```

Now, I came across the workspace concept in `vscode`. I want to add a workspaces definition into the root of the overall project and enjoy the advantage of only having one `vscode` window. This would be such a `my_project/code-workspace` file:

```json
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "name": "ROOT",
      "path": "."
    },
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "path": "./backend"
    },
    {
      "name": "frontend",
      "path": "./frontend"
    },
  ]
}
```

However, I do not manage to let `vscode` open the DevContainers of the sub-projects.

I succeeded to place a `.devcontainer/` folder into the root folder of the overall project, which opens one DevContainer and connects to it for both sub-projects. But that is not what I want.

What is wrong? Is my wanted setup possible with the internal architecture of `VSCode` managing the different settings, areas, agent-connects, etc?